# Protobuf new field not showing

Tags: kotlin, protocol-buffers, grpc, artifactory, intellij-13

I have updated my protos files as:

```
message XYZ {

  string a = 1;

  repeated=Detail b = 2;

  // New field added
  CustomType c = 3;
}
```

This is maintained in a repo which when successfully run in spinnaker uploads to artifactory. The jar file uploaded there has the correct fields etc. However when I try to access this same version of protos which is uploaded in artifactory in a separate repo, I am unable to access the field c in message XYZ. I am using intelliJ and kotlin, and have tried refreshing maven as well as deleting cache. Can anyone please help here?

Comment: You have a typo in .proto.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue, seems there was some issue in versioning. The file downloaded in artifactory had the new field however the same version which my code was referring to and that got downloaded did not have this field. Soln: Bumped up the version.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).